# Connection to router loops after resetting the router

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-router

**The full details:**
My internet is very finicky, but not so much so that it's a huge problem. My computer is the main problem.

After the router is turned off it says like normal "Not connected to an internet" and I can open a list of networks from my tray.

Then once my router is turned back on, there is a possibility that my computer tries to connect to it but ends up failing to connect completely. If it does fail to connect, it is impossible to open up the networks list from clicking on the internet access icon in the tray.

Actually, it is impossible to access any of the networks at all after it fails to connect to the router as I believe it is stuck in some sort of loop. I can't disconnect from my original router and I can't open up the networks list to refresh connections.

**The only fix for this is to restart my computer.** And this turns into a hassle when I'm working on some projects and it takes about 5 minutes to have my computer in a proper running state after logging in, and then another 5 or more minutes to check for updates on my program. ( also, after restarting my computer there's a possibility that my program runs into errors so I am very hesitant on restarting my computer ).

**What I Think can fix it, but don't know where to start or look**

First, the biggest problem is that after the connection fails I need to open up the networks tray. ( at least it will let me see if my computer can find other networks )

Second, I need to be able to stop this loop trying to connect to my router somehow. I believe if I can completely turn off my wifi and then turn it back on it will reset.

Additional information:
It's a Dell running windows 7.

*Please ask for any extra information if necessary.*

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't been able to recreate my situation in a while, I have found what I think is a fix. ( ***If it isn't I'll fix my answer*** )

Trying to recreate the situation I accidentally disabled the network driver and had to find it and enable it. This driver seems to be responsible for connecting to routers so I could disable it whenever it acts up.

All you need to do is open up your control panel, click on hardware and sound, then under devices and printers you should find **Device Manager**. Click that, and go to view, select **hidden devices** and disable/enable the driver in your `network adapters` that looks similar to "wireless #####".